# DES Encryption in Android

Tags: android, des

If I try encrypting "123456" with the key `qwertykey` I get `UVEXg9fgBxo=` as response with the online tool https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/.

But if I use android code I am getting `2XQNkfXlN6E=` as encrypted value.

Can anyone explain to me how this can be achieved?

My code is:

```java
public String encrypt(String plainTextPassword){
    String encrypted = "";
    try{
        DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec("qwertykey".getBytes());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        byte[] cleartext = plainTextPassword.getBytes();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES"); // cipher is not thread safe
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(cleartext),Base64.DEFAULT);

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: print exception in `catch` block...

Comment: Make sure you use the same parameters (mode, iv) as the online tool (which by the way is a bit dubious).

Comment: Are you using spongy castle jar for encryption and decryption ??

Comment: DES is not secure anymore. Also key usage in your code is not the best way. Check [this](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/) library for a secure implementation of AES algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DES supports only a key size of 56 bit (64 bit with parity). So you cannot use a larger key with it. Mcrypt knows this and silently only uses the first 8 bytes. Mcrypt also doesn't implement proper padding. Instead it pads with 0x00 bytes. You should be able to use a similar, but not same, padding in BouncyCastle:

```
Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/ZeroBytePadding", "BC");
```

Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14487/can-someone-explain-the-ecb-penguin). It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like CBC or CTR. It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a padding oracle attack are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an encrypt-then-MAC scheme.

**NOTE** DES should not be used at all for new developments.

Comment: Yeah thats true